# How to upgrade JDK from Oracle to Zulu in redhat linux

Tags: java, azul-zulu

I want to upgrade my Linux JDK from Oracle to **Azul-Zulu**.can someone helps me to do this.
What to do after downloading the tar.gz Zulu package?
I see that after extracting the downloaded package we need to put it in the path where we need to access java. Is that correct or what we can do more like setting environment variables etc.

Comment: You can define JAVA_HOME environment variable, but that is not mandatory. You can run many java programs without defining JAVA_HOME. Some applications written in Java, like Eclipse IDE, do look for JAVA_HOME.

Comment: If you are not sure what to do with archive better opt for installers, which will do all configuration for you. There is a whole range of them on the Zulu download site: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your question depends on *what* you actually want to start with the JDK. Sometimes is is sufficient to change the path to java binary in a start script, e.g. Eclipse or Tomcat, sometimes you also need to setup the variable JAVA_HOME.

To setup the java for yourself only:

Check your shell by running echo $SHELL

```
-> /bin/bash
-> /bin/zsh
-> /bin/tcsh
```

or something like that Locate your shell's config file:

```
bash: ~/.bashrc
zsh: ~/.zshrc
tcsh: ~/.cshrc or ~/.tcshrc
```

and optionally most of the shells: ~/.profile or ~/.login check those file(s) if you already have variable declarations for: JAVA_HOME JRE_HOME (and rarely seen) SDK_HOME JDK_HOME

check whether any of those files contain a setup for the variable PATH (probably has)

If you found any of the *_HOME variables from above you can change them to reflect your new java home directory: e.g. zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64 located under /opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64 would mean to set the variables as follows: zsh and bash:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64
export JRE_HOME=/opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64
```

tcsh

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64
setenv JRE_HOME /opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64
```

SDK_HOME and JDK_HOME may point to the above locations as well but are normally unused.

If you located your PATH somewhere it may read something like this: zsh and bash:

```
 export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

tcsh:

```
 setenv PATH ~/bin:$PATH
```

In order for your new java to appear "before" the "other" java you need to update (or create if missing) this to e.g.: zsh and bash:

```
 export PATH=~/bin:/opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64/bin:$PATH
```

tcsh:

```
 setenv PATH ~/bin:/opt/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-linux_x64/bin:$PATH
```

After completely logging out and in again your JAVA_HOME and PATH can be controlled in a shell like this:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME    -> should point to *your* java folder
echo $PATH         -> should contain *your* java folder's bin directroy
which java         -> should list the new java binary instead of /bin/java or /usr/bin/java
```

BTW: the variables JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME and PATH may also be set in a startscript, e.g. catalina.sh for tomcat or the eclipse.ini for eclipse if you do not want to modify your environment.

If you download the RPM/DEB instead of the tar.gz and install the package you (may) not need configure anything since the packages might re-configure your system for you

Cheers, Holger

Comment: holle2de, thanks for the answer, and that would be helpful. Can you please tell me how do I install Zulu Jdk as a java alternative? So that If my application is having any issues with Zulu JDK I can revert it back

Comment: @Devika please download the appropriate version for your system and unpack/install to your likeness.

Comment: @Devika I would use the Zip/tar.gz Archive and unpack it in e.g. /opt or ~/ (given you are using Linux of Mac OS)